# Can't run PopSQL in Ubuntu 18.04 with node v11.2.0

Tags: mysql, node.js

To learn MySQL I installed PopSQL using .deb package but it's not working, when I launch PopSQL from terminal with `sudo popsql` I get these error in the terminal and PopSQL ui shows blank screen.

```
{"name":"PopSQL","hostname":"ivyRose","pid":16621,"level":30,"msg":"Starting app. Look for crash reports in /tmp and error logs in /home/neon/.config/PopSQL/error.log","time":"2018-11-22T12:15:27.927Z","v":0}

(popsql:16621): IBUS-WARNING **: 18:00:28.174: The owner of /home/neon/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
[Oracle] NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 8.2.1 (linux, x64)
Node.js require() error was: 
  DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
Node.js require() mapped to /opt/PopSQL/resources/app.asar/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

[ODBC] libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PopSQL to learn MySQL.

But, if you want it, to get it going, follow the error message instructions:

1. download the Instant Client Basic Light package from
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
2. unzip it
3. add the directory to your library search path, either via LD_LIBRARY_PATH or using ldconfig (I recommend the latter), as shown at
   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst

PopSQL should use a try/catch block when it requires oracledb so you don't see the error.

Comment: after installing Instant Client Basic Light package I was able to run PopSQL using gksu popsql command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the required driver from mysql. You can download and install this from

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

The answer here should help.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/800216/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-install-odbc?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Downloaded zip contains libmyodbc8a.so, libmyodbc8S.so and libmyodbc8w.so in /lib folder, there's no libmyodbc5a.so and libodbcmyS.so
Do I even need popSQL? It's not necessary to use MySQL so can't I just use MySQL workbench?
Today is my first day in MySQL world so I am kinda lost.